# Weird eval output

Tags: javascript, eval

Try the below code snippet, it is giving weird results. Could anyone explain it?

```
var s = "10+10";
alert("Evaluation 1: " + eval(s+s+s)); // 2040
alert("Evaluation 2: " + eval(s+2));   // 112
```

Output that I am expecting is 30 and 22

Comment: what is the output???

Comment: What is the expected output ?...

Comment: I get 2040 (eval("10+1010+1010+10")) and 112 (eval("10+102")) in the two alert boxes, which makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: i hate how people bash newbies with minus votes

Comment: I suppose most of downvoters are waiting what *weird* result they need to talking about so they can revert the vote. Results and expectations are both missing here, so what's the OP question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing weird about it at all:

```
s + s + s === "10+10" + "10+10" + "10+10" === "10+1010+1010+10" => 2040
s + 2 === "10+10" + "2" === "10+102" => 112
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanantion. I didn't took the concatenation into account

Answer (score -4):

Take the `s` variable out of quotes:

```
var s = 10 + 10;
```

**RETURNS**

Evaluation 1: 60

Evaluation 2: 22